# How to find files in ClearCase that are both checkedout and have a specific extension file

Tags: grep, clearcase

In ClearCase I can find CHECKEDOUT files (on my view ) with

```
cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -all | sort -r
```

but I want to apply a regexp to filter only those that are c++ (c,h) source codes and apply on the checkedout files. The filter is

```
$targettedFileFilter="\\.\(c[cxp]*\|h[h]{0,1}\|sig\)\$";
```

I tried these two alternatives

**Alternative 1:**

```
find . -type f -regextype  posix-awk -regex ".*$targettedFileFilter" && cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -d /vobs/rbs/hw/ru_fpga/txl/sw | sort -r
```

Pitfall: but it takes a long time scanning all files.

**Alternative 2:**

```
cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -all | sort -r | grep -E '*.cc' 
cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -all | sort -r | grep -E '*.h' 
....
```

Pitfall: too much code, and need to save all outputs

**Is there a way to list checked out files and apply a filter?**

Comment: Why not grep -E '\.(cc|h)'?

Comment: I don't know why I have not taught that. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I will post an answer later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering [`grep -E` (`--extended-regexp`) is able to interpret regexp (without needing to escape its special characters)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50514/7490), all you need to type is:

```
cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -all | sort -r | grep -E '\.(cc|h)'
```

Pattern or wildcards are not mentioned in [`cleartool lsco`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm).

As [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888947/how-to-find-files-in-clearcase-that-are-both-checkedout-and-have-a-specific-exte/46894797#comment80775318_46894797):

```
cleartool lsco -me -short -cview -all | grep -E '\.(cc|h)$'  | sort -r
```

Comment: I'd reverse the grep and sort pipes, if only because I've seen some pretty long outputs from lsco, and it might be best to limit the output before sorting it. Oh, it may also be a good idea to eliminate any false positives caused by ".cc" or ".h" in the middle of the file by using the $ anchor from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124462/detecting-pattern-at-the-end-of-a-line-with-grep

Comment: @BrianCowan Good point. I have implemented your suggestion in the answer for more visibility.